# How to Destroy FooTable Instance

Tags: jquery, footable

I've been trying to figure out how to destroy FooTable Instance but I can't get It to work. What I want to do is destroy the FooTable instance on modal close (I'm using semantic UI modal), so that when the modal is triggered the table reinitializes itself. Content of the table has 1090 row which I can see when I do `FooTable.get('#myTable').rows.all`, as well as the pagination rows in `FooTable.get('#myTable').rows.array` (I'm setting size for pagination to 16 (i.e 16 rows per page) )

Now what I want is when I do the following;

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    onHide: function() {
        var ft = FooTable.get('#myTable');
        ft.destroy();
    }
});
```

The rows of #myTable should be reverted back to all 1090 but instead, FooTable doesn't return all tables back, it only destroys itself (removing all classes and removing the pagination but it doesn't return all the table rows back to the default number of rows (in my case 1090 number of rows ) ).

How can I get Footable to add all table rows to the table upon destruction? or is there any workaround to this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to destroy your Footable? And have you tried to change Footable page size before destroy with `FooTable.get('#table-id').pageSize(newSize)`?

Comment: I need to destroy the footable because users can re-open the modal multiple times and each time the modal is reopened  footable only sees the first page of the item and re-init that, which makes the pagination to goes off. trying out increasing the pageSize()